# How to use C# LINQ Union to get the Union of Custom list1 with list2

Tags: c#, linq, union, extension-methods

I am using the `Enumerable.Union<TSource>` method to get the union of the Custom List1 with the Custom List2. But somehow it does not work as it should in my case. I am getting all the items also the duplicate once.

I followed the [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the work done, but still I am not able to achieve the same.

Following is the Code of the custom class:-

```
public class CustomFormat : IEqualityComparer<CustomFormat>
{
    private string mask;

    public string Mask
    {
        get { return mask; }
        set { mask = value; }
    }

    private int type;//0 for Default 1 for userdefined

    public int Type
    {
         get { return type; }
         set { type = value; }
    }
    public CustomFormat(string c_maskin, int c_type)
    {
        mask = c_maskin;
        type = c_type;
    }

    public bool Equals(CustomFormat x, CustomFormat y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal. 
        return x != null && y != null && x.Mask.Equals(y.Mask) && x.Type.Equals(y.Type);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CustomFormat obj)
    {
        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        int hashProductName = obj.Mask == null ? 0 : obj.Mask.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field. 
        int hashProductCode = obj.Type.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

This I am calling as follows:-

```
List<CustomFormat> l1 = new List<CustomFormat>();
l1.Add(new CustomFormat("#",1));
l1.Add(new CustomFormat("##",1));
l1.Add(new CustomFormat("###",1));
l1.Add(new CustomFormat("####",1));

List<CustomFormat> l2 = new List<CustomFormat>();
l2.Add(new CustomFormat("#",1));
l2.Add(new CustomFormat("##",1));
l2.Add(new CustomFormat("###",1));
l2.Add(new CustomFormat("####",1));
l2.Add(new CustomFormat("## ###.0",1));

l1 = l1.Union(l2).ToList();

foreach(var l3 in l1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(l3.Mask + " " + l3.Type);
}
```

Please suggest the appropriate way to achieve the same!

Comment: It seems odd, but your code works if you a) provide a parameterless constructor for CustomFormat, and pass an instance of that class to the Union method - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/YTVwTI. The question then is why Union is ignoring the implementation of IEqualityComparer<CustomFormat> within the class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The oddity here is that your class implement `IEqualityComparer<CustomClass>` instead of `IEquatable<CustomClass>`. You *could* pass in another instance of `CustomClass` which would be used as the comparer, but it would be more idiomatic to just make `CustomClass` implement `IEquatable<CustomClass>`, and also override `Equals(object)`.

The difference between `IEquatable<T>` and `IEqualityComparer<T>` is that `IEquatable<T>` says "I know how to compare myself with another instance of `T`" whereas `IEqualityComparer<T>` says "I know how to compare two instances of `T`". The latter is normally provided separately - just as it can be provided to `Union` via another parameter. It's very rare for a type to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` for its own type - whereas `IEquatable<T>` should pretty much *only* be used to compare values of the same type.

Here's an implementation using automatically implemented properties for simplicity and more idiomatic parameter names. I'd probably change the hash code implementation myself and use expression-bodied members, but that's a different matter.

```
public class CustomFormat : IEquatable<CustomFormat>
{
    public string Mask { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

    public CustomFormat(string mask, int type)
    {
        Mask = mask;
        Type = type;
    }

    public bool Equals(CustomFormat other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return other != null && other.Mask == Mask && other.Type == Type;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as CustomFormat);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        int hashProductName = Mask == null ? 0 : Mask.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field. 
        int hashProductCode = Type.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

Now it doesn't help that (as noted in comments) the documentation for [`Enumerable.Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) is wrong. It currently states:

> The default equality comparer, `Default`, is used to compare values of the types that implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` generic interface.

It should say something like:

> The default equality comparer, `Default`, is used to compare values when a specific `IEqualityComparer<T>` is not provided. If `T` implements `IEquatable<T>`, the default comparer will use that implementation. Otherwise, it will use the implementation of `Equals(object)`.

Comment: I tried implementing but it does not seem to solve the issue. Please see the code [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YTVwTI). It shows no error but duplicate items are shown.

Comment: @JDoshi: That fiddle still implements `IEqualityComparer<T>`. The code I've given (implementing `IEquatable<T>` instead) *does* work with the example you gave.

Comment: Actually I edited in that same fiddle and shared the link with you which was orignally shared by stuartd . So you accidently shared wrong fiddle. Sorry for the mistake :(

Comment: @JDoshi: Your code doesn't *override* `Object.GetHashCode`. Instead, it's still implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode`. If you'd used the code in my answer, it would have been fine - and likewise you'd have seen that as a problem if you'd looked at the compiler warnings (that you were overriding `Equals` but not `GetHashCode`). Always pay attention to warnings.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass an instance of an `IEqualityComparer` to the `Union` method. The method has an overload to pass in your comparer.

The easiest and ugliest solution is

```
var comparer = new CustomFormat(null,0);

l1 = l1.Union(l2, comparer).ToList();
```

You have made some mistakes in your implementation. You should not implement the `IEqualityComparer` method on your type (`CustomFormat`), but on a separate class, like `CustomFormatComparer`.

On your type (`CustomFormat`) you should implemented `IEquatable`.

Comment: The MSDN link for Union is misleading, then, as it says _"The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of the types that implement the IEqualityComparer<T> generic interface. **To compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type**."_ it doesn't stipulate this must be in a separate class.

Comment: @Jehof Can you please explain the use of `IEquatable` in this case. Here implementing `IEquatable` directly and not `IEqualityComparer` yields in error since `Union` is used.

Comment: @JDoshi: No, it doesn't - implementing `IEquatable<T>` really is the way forward here.